# Problema al evitar registros duplicados

Tags: php, javascript, sql

Antes de nada quiero decir que ya he revisado las posibles respuestas a esto en este y otros foros. Tal cual como indica el titulo lo que quiero hacer es: si existe un registro con el mismo numero lanzar una aletra con js y si no si no, realizar el registro de los nuevos datos. Estoy utilizando Dreamweaver, por eso el orden y el nombre de algunas variables, aparte no se si esto puede afectar mi codigo con respecto a lo que quiero hacer.

```
$consulta = mysql_query("SELECT NUMERO_PLANILLA FROM huawei_rollout WHERE 
NUMERO_PLANILLA = '$NUMERO_PLANILLA'", $conexion);
if(mysql_num_rows($consulta) > 0){
     echo '<script>alert("El numero de Planilla ya existe");</script>';
 }else{

if((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "frmGuardar")) {
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO huawei_rollout (ID, FECHA, MES_EJECUCION, 
MES_FACTURACION, CONTRATISTA) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",

                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['ID'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['FECHA'], "date"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['MES_EJECUCION'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['MES_FACTURACION'], "text"));



mysql_select_db($database_conexion, $conexion);
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $conexion) or die(mysql_error());

$insertGoTo = "ingre_plani_exi.php";
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
$insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}
header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}
```

}

Comment: Primero, mysql_query ya esta descartado deberias pasar a mysqli o PDO,  pregunta, que error se te presenta?

Comment: Yo se que esta obsoleto, pero es la versión que hay en el server, y el problema es que me deja insertar datos duplicados y no me lanza la alerta si esta duplicado.

Comment: que versión manejas?

Comment: 5.1, pero no creo que sea el problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta respuesta ya tiene varios dias, pero la posteo por si a alguien le sirve, quiero aclarar de algunas variables esta asi por que lo hice desde dreamweaver.

```
$NUMERO_PLANILLA = $_POST['NUMERO_PLANILLA'];

mysql_select_db($database_conexion, $conexion);
$query_numero_planilla = "SELECT NUMERO_PLANILLA FROM huawei_rollout WHERE 
NUMERO_PLANILLA = '$NUMERO_PLANILLA'";
$numero_planilla = mysql_query($query_numero_planilla, $conexion) or 
die(mysql_error());
$row_numero_planilla = mysql_fetch_assoc($numero_planilla);
if(mysql_num_rows($numero_planilla)>0){
echo '<script>alert("Ya existe el numero de planilla ingresado");</script>';
echo '<script>document.write("Redireccionando...");
setTimeout("window.history.go(-1)",1000); </script>';
}else{

query="INSERT INTO huawei_rollout (ID, F..."<COSULTA DE INSERTAR>...");
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya que (mysql_num_rows($consulta) > 0){ no te esta funcionando, prueba lo siguiente:

```
       $consulta = mysql_query("SELECT NUMERO_PLANILLA FROM huawei_rollout WHERE 
        NUMERO_PLANILLA = '$NUMERO_PLANILLA'", $conexion);

$numpero_plantilla = 0;
while ($fila = mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta)) {
    $numpero_plantilla = $fila['NUMERO_PLANILLA'];
}

if($numpero_plantilla  = 0){
    echo '<script>alert("El numero de Planilla ya existe");</script>';
}else{

    if((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "frmGuardar"){
       $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO huawei_rollout (ID, FECHA, MES_EJECUCION, 
MES_FACTURACION, CONTRATISTA) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",

    GetSQLValueString($_POST['ID'], "int"),
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['FECHA'], "date"),
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['MES_EJECUCION'], "text"),
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['MES_FACTURACION'], "text"));



    mysql_select_db($database_conexion, $conexion);
    $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $conexion) or die(mysql_error());

    $insertGoTo = "ingre_plani_exi.php";
    if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
        $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
        $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    }
    header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}
```

Lo de la versión te lo preguntaba ya que puedes usar PDO a partir de la 5.1, solo debes activar las extensiones, si te interesa saber como hacerlo en PDO te puedo dejar la respuesta de como seria en PDO

Comment: Y lo de PDO te lo agradezco pero no puedo cambiar la version (y)

Comment: Si estás en la v. 5.1 puedes y **debes** usar PDO. No tienes por qué ceñirte a un manejo de los datos obsoleto e inseguro. Además, cuando el servidor se actualice a la v. 7, el  código que use funciones mysql_. quedará sin funcionar. Saludos.